# Reload top of the div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to get scroll bar to the top of the page. below code do what exactly I want.

```
.Flipped, .Flipped .list
{ 
transform:rotateX(180deg);
-ms-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

This is my div

```
<div class="lists Flipped" style="margin-top: -50px; z-index: 10;">
```

This is my css.

```
.lists {
display: flex;
overflow-x: auto;
width: 100%;
flex: 0 0 auto;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

But after I used this, when I try to reload the page it is load bottom of the div. I want to load the top of the div. How can I fix this issue.

This is how the page is loading.
[image]

This is how I want.
[image]

Comment: can u plz share ur screen? or add this in codepen?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do, is it related to page reload or scrollbar ?

Comment: @Manikandan2811   I edit the question.

Comment: You will probably have to use JavaScript for that, to explicitly _set_ the scroll position of the element.